# Array of strings sent to WebService gets truncated

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a C# WebApi method with this signature:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getbyid/{date}")]
public Response Get(DateTime date, [FromBody] List<string> ids)
```

When I call this method from Postman with a list of n strings in the body, everything works fine.  My list simply looks like

```
["id1","id2","id3"...]
```

But when I wrote a small C# client to call it, I am finding that the array gets truncated.  It is not an issue of message size.  If I send 100 items, somewhere between 75-80 make it to the service.  If I send 500 about 475 make it.  I confirmed with logging that the list has 500 items right before calling the service, and less than 500 right inside the controller.

Here is my client code:

```
string url = ".../getbyid/2017-01-01";
List<string> payload = new List<string>();
// logic to put 500 items in the list
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
json.Serialize(jsonWriter, payload);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (responseStream == null) throw new EndOfStreamException();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
// do processing...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a writer.Close(); line. This sounds like a stream that hasnt flushed all it's writes

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks!  I added that line before the GetResponse call and all the results now make it to the service.

Answer (score 0):

If your POST is passing the parameters via URL(which I think your URL routing is set to do), you are limited to the length of the URL at something like 2800 characters.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, that wasn't the issue as I had the same problem whether passing in 100 or 500 results.  But thanks for the reply.